# iterate through a loop multiple numbers at a time

Tags: javascript

how can i iterate through a loop more than 1 index at a time and stop when the highest index reaches a certain number?
[I saw this article](http://perl6maven.com/perl6-looping-over-a-list-of-values-one-at-a-time-two-at-a-time-and-more) but could'nt translate this into javascript.

```
var i,j,k;
i = j = k = 0;
while(k<100){
    j = i+1;
    k = i+2;
    console.log(i+' '+j+' '+k); // k reaches 101
    i = i+3;  
}
```

Comment: You increment "k" inside the loop **after** you've tested it.  Move the `console.log()` call to before the line where you increment "k".

Comment: @Pointy but then `i=99 j=100 k=98`

Comment: At a glance, it sounds like you need either the number of iterations to be divisible by 1, 2, and or you need checks to not iterate over all three values if you exceed the desired number of iterations

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to see?  The way you're incrementing the variables is really bizarre.

Comment: @Pointy i am trying to go thru the loop with 3 index numbers at a time. i have an array and would like to reference 3 items each loop pass

Comment: Add `Expected output` and `Actual output` to your question to make things more clear

Comment: Then why not just use `k = k + 3` instead of relying on "i"?

Comment: @steaks i think you are correct,  since k is the 3rd number, there is a remainder when dividing into 100

Comment: What do you expect to see when limit (100 for this case) is not divisible by the number of items per iteration (3 for this case)?  Do you expect to see the last iteration (just 99 for this case), or do you expect to not see that iteration (only 0 - 98 for this case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of these answers are good answers.  However, none of these answers offer a solution where the last (non full) iteration is included if the limit of the loop (100 in this case) isn't divisible by the number of items per iteration (3 in this case).  In other words, non of the answers log "99" for the OP.  So I added a solution that satisfies this criteria and is general for any limit or itemsPerIteration where limit and itemsPerIteration are natural numbers.

```
function multipleItemsForLoop(limit, itemsPerIteration, callback) {
    var loop = function(i) {
        var numItemsThisIteration = Math.min(limit - i, itemsPerIteration);
        if(numItemsThisIteration <= 0) {
            return;
        }
        var itemIndecies = [];
        for(var x = 0; x < numItemsThisIteration; x++) {
            itemIndecies.push(i+x);
        }

        callback(itemIndecies);

        loop(i+itemsPerIteration > limit && numItemsThisIteration === itemsPerIteration ? i + 1 : i + itemsPerIteration);
    }

    loop(0);
}

multipleItemsForLoop(100, 3, function (itemIndecies) { console.log(itemIndecies); } );
```

Comment: why are you putting an argument that has not been declared? `...function(itemIndecies){...}`

Comment: `mutlipleItemsForLoop` has three paramters.  The third paramter, `callback`, expects a function.  Therefore, I am passing in a function: `function (itemIndecies) { console.log(itemIndecies); }` as the `callback` argument for `multipleItemsForLoop`.  You'll notice that the function I pass in expects one argument.  You can see why by looking at how we use `callback` in `multipleItemsForLoop`.  We use `callback` in `multipleItemsForLoop` by executing it like a function that has one paramter.  This may not be clear...passing in functions as arguments to other functions is a difficult concept!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want it to stop before k reaches > 100.

If so change your while loop into a do... while loop. That way, it evaluates the condition at the end of an iteration.

```
do{
        j = i+1;
        console.log(i+' '+j+' '+k);
        k = i+2;
        i = i+3;
} while (k<100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you wanted something more of the form

```
var i, j, k = 0;
while (k < 99) {
    k = (j = (i = k + 1) + 1) + 1;
    console.log('i', i, 'j', j, 'k', k);
}
```

so you get

```
i 1 j 2 k 3
i 4 j 5 k 6
...
i 97 j 98 k 99
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want

```
var i = 0,
    j = 1,
    k = 2;
while (k < 100) {
    console.log(i+' '+j+' '+k);
    i += 3;
    j += 3;
    k += 3;
}
```

Or, more concise, in a for-loop:

```
for (var i=0, j=1, k=2; k < 100; k=1+(j=1+(i+=3))) {
    console.log(i+' '+j+' '+k);
}
```

Yet, usually you wouldn't use three variable for that. Instead, just make it

```
for (var i=0; i<100-2; i+=3) {
    console.log(i+' '+(i+1)+' '+(i+2));
}
// or
for (var k=2; k<100; k+=3) {
    console.log((k-2)+' '+(k-1)+' '+k);
}
```

Comment: Note, this only logs 0 - 98.  That may not be what the OP wants.  We can't tell from his question though...