# How to Validate multiple passport numbers at a time which is having any duplicate is there in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I had a scenario in my Angular 7 application . I had a form it need to allow 10 customer to book their flight tickets as a group. At the time of entering their details i want to validate any of two members are using same passport number. How to Validate multiple passport numbers at a time.

Please help me

I searched in google and ind below link and unable to understand will it useful to me or not
[iterate through a loop multiple numbers at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826226/iterate-through-a-loop-multiple-numbers-at-a-time)

Comment: use a FormArray and a custom validator

Answer (score 0):

Not at all special to angular or Javascript.

Simply sort the passport numbers (maybe after stripping out spaces and similar characters).
Then iterate over the sorted data and check if the current entry is not the last and not equal to the next entry.
If you run into case where two subsequent entries are equal you found a duplicate. If you don't there is none because you sorted the data before.